# Tangential projection $P: \Gamma \to T_\Gamma$ or $P: V(\Gamma) \to V(T_\Gamma)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, operator-theory, manifolds, vector-fields

If $P$ is a tangential projection onto the tangent plane $T_\Gamma$ of a surface $\Gamma$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^d$, defined for $x \in \Gamma$ by 
\begin{align}
P(x) = I - n(x) \otimes n(x)
\end{align}
where $n$ is the unit normal on $x$. Then it gives the tangential gradient of any vector field $v: \Gamma \to \mathbb{R}^d$ that
\begin{align}
\nabla_\Gamma v = P \nabla v
\end{align}

My question is quite simple: Should we say the tangential projection $P: \Gamma \to T_\Gamma$, or $P: V(\Gamma) \to V(T_\Gamma)$ for a function space $V$?

The definition looks like $P: \Gamma \ni x \mapsto x \in T_\Gamma$, while the tangential gradient acts on a vector field that is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ takes elements of the tangent bundle $T\Bbb R^d$ to elements of the tangent bundle of $\Gamma$. But it only applies to elements of $T_x\Bbb R^d$, where $x \in \Gamma$.

My own choice here would be to name the name the inclusion map
$$
i : \Gamma \to \Bbb R^d : x \mapsto x.
$$
Then let 
$$
\zeta = i^{*} (T\Bbb R^d)
$$
be the restriction of the tangent bundle of $\Bbb R^d$ to $\Gamma$. Now  $P$ is a bundle map from $\zeta$ to $T\Gamma$:
$$
P : \zeta \to T\Gamma.
$$

To answer what you asked: $P$ is definitely *not* a map from $\Gamma$ to $T\Gamma$, for the argument to $P$ is a vector tangent to $\Gamma$, not a point of euclidean space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have enough knowledge about differential geometry, so I don't understand what the difference is between "$T_x \mathbb{R}^d$ for $x \in \Gamma$" and "$T\Gamma$". I think $i$ is just an identity mapping, but how to understand $i^*(T_x \mathbb{R}^d)$? In addition, is the statement $P: V(\Gamma) \to V(T\Gamma)$ still wrong?

Comment: $T\Gamma$ denotes the tangent bundle to the surface $\Gamma$ -- the collection of all tangent planes to $\Gamma$, considered as a vector bundle with base space $\Gamma$. $T_x\Gamma$ is the single tangent plane at the point $x \in \Gamma$. $I^{*}$ denotes the "pullback" operation on vector bundles; informally, it means "consider all tangent vectors to $R^d$...but then only consider the ones that start from points in $\Gamma$ -- it's like restricting a function to a subset of its domain, but for bundles. For your last question: I don't know what $V$ denotes, so I cannot answer.

Comment: Thank you! What are "all tangent vectors to $R^d$"? I think vectors can only be tangent to a surface but how can they be tangent to a Euclidean space?

Comment: $\Bbb R^n$ is a smooth manifold (arguably it's the prototype for all smooth manifolds), hence it has a tangent space. Since there are about 8 equivalent definitions of tangent space or tangent vector, and I don't know which one you're using, it's tough to describe it to you. But one version of things is that a tangent vector or $\Bbb R^n$ at a point $p \in \Bbb R^n$ is a pair $(p; v)$, where $v$ is any vector in $\Bbb R^n$. The set $T_pR^n$ has a nice vector-space structure: $(p; v) + (p; w) = (p; v+w); \alpha (p; v) = (p, \alpha v)$. Hence we call it "the tangent (vector) space at $p$."